# correlationId propagated to spring sleuth 1.x

Tags: spring-cloud, slf4j, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have the following setup:

Proxy (P) -- HTTP --> Spring Boot 2 app (X) -- HTTP --> Spring Boot 1 app (Y)

The proxy sends the `requestId` as an HTTP header which I need to include in the logs of both X and Y.

For the X app I could easily do it with the support of Spring Cloud Sleuth 2 using

`spring:
  sleuth:
    propagation-keys: requestId`

and creating a `CurrentTraceContext` implementation with inspiration from `Slf4jCurrentTraceContext` where I add

`MDC.put("requestId", ExtraFieldPropagation.get(currentSpan, "requestId"));`

and then I can easily add it to the logs using the following log pattern:

`%d{yy-MM-dd E HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p [component=${springAppName},requestId=%X{requestId:-}] %m%n"`

But now I need to propagate the `requestId` also to Y app.

Unfortunately there I cannot leverage the goodies introduced in Spring Cloud Sleuth 2.0, (like TraceContext from brave library) since that is a Spring Boot 1.x app.

Wondering what are the options?

I was thinking to extend the `Slf4jSpanLogger` and inject into `DefaultTracer` but not sure how to get the `requestId` there is no TraceContext in SpanLogger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requestId` has to be there in the headers. You would have to modify the current logic of parsing the HTTP headers for Boot 1.x and retrieve that value from the headers and put it in the span.

The easiest way however would be to propagate that value as baggage cause baggage works out of the box for Boot 1.x. That way if we see the `baggage-` prefixed headers, Sleuth 1.3.x will automatically propagate it. Remember to whitelist the baggage in Boot 2.0.

Comment: thanks Marcin! I tried you suggestion but still it doesn't work. I included my playground project here: https://github.com/altfatterz/spring-cloud-sleuth-demo

Comment: That is very surprising. Have you added the baggage entries in properties in the `2.0.x` based application? Can you upload the sample somewhere?

Comment: made it work, in the end, I don't need to use the `spring.sleuth.baggage-keys`, with `spring.sleuth.propagation-keys` it is propagated as a header and then with a servlet filter in the spring boot 1.x app I am extract it with a filter and putting into MDC. Details here https://github.com/altfatterz/spring-cloud-sleuth-demo